# AWS hosted website not working with non-www. But working fine with www

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect, url-rewriting, no-www

My domain is with godaddy and files are hosted on aws.

website properly working with **www.mydomain.abc**, but giving error with **mydomain.abc**

How can I redirect www.mydomain.abc to mydomain.abc

using these redirect rules in .htaccess

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.abc
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.abc/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: did you add CNAME "@" to you dns settings ?

Comment: No. how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an alias to `www` from the root domain in your zone:

```
@ IN A 172.17.2.0
www IN CNAME @
```

To confirm this, ping both 'www.example.com' and 'example.com' and confirm they return the same address.

**Update:** I corrected the answer per Michael SQL Bot comment below

Comment: That might appear to work, but it's wrong.  A CNAME at the root violates the constraint that no other record can coexist at the same level as a CNAME, which means your NS and SOA records are invalid and the entire zone is not as it should be.  This is why Route 53 created A-record alises -- they don't violate the constraint.